# Breadth-first algorithm implementation

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search

I am trying to implement a "Breadth-First" Algorithm as a variation of something I've seen in a book.

My issue is that the algorithm is not adding the elements of every node into the queue.

For instance, if I search for "black lab" under the name 'mariela' in the "search()" function, I will get the correct output: "simon is a black lab"

However, I ought to be able to look for "black lab" in "walter", which is connected to "mariela", which is connected to "simon", who is a "black lab'. This is not working.

Have I made a rookie mistake in my implementation of this algorithm, or have I set up my graph wrong?

As always, any/all help is much appreciated!

```
from collections import deque


# TEST GRAPH -------------
graph = {}
graph['walter'] = ['luci', 'kaiser', 'andrea', 'mariela']
graph['andrea'] = ['echo', 'dante', 'walter', 'mariela']
graph['mariela'] = ['ginger', 'simon', 'walter', 'andrea']
graph['kaiser'] = 'german shepherd'
graph['luci'] = 'black cat'
graph['echo'] = 'pitbull'
graph['dante'] = 'pitbull'
graph['ginger'] = 'orange cat'
graph['simon'] = 'black lab'



def condition_met(name):
    if graph[name] == 'black lab':
        return name


def search(name):
    search_queue = deque()
    search_queue += graph[name]             # add all elements of    "name" to queue
    searchedAlready = []                    # holding array for people    already searched through

while search_queue:                     # while queue not empty...
    person = search_queue.popleft()     # pull 1st person from queue
    if person not in searchedAlready:   # if person hasn't been searched through yet...
        if condition_met(person):
            print person + ' is a black labrador'
            return True
    else:
        search_queue += graph[person]
        searchedAlready.append(person)
return False


 search('walter')
#search('mariela')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lots of problems in your implementation - both Python and Algorithm wise.

Rewrite as:

```
# @param graph  graph to search
# @param start  the node to start at
# @param value  the value to search for
def search(graph, start, value):
  explored = []
  queue = [start]
  while len(queue) > 0:
    # next node to explore
    node = queue.pop()
    # only explore if not already explored
    if node not in explored:
      # node found, search complete
      if node == value:
        return True
      # add children of node to queue
      else:
        explored.append(node)
        queue.extend(graph[node]) # extend is faster than concat (+=)
  return False


graph = {}
graph['walter'] = ['luci', 'kaiser', 'andrea', 'mariela']
graph['andrea'] = ['echo', 'dante', 'walter', 'mariela']
graph['mariela'] = ['ginger', 'simon', 'walter', 'andrea']

# children should be a list
graph['kaiser'] = ['german shepherd'] 
graph['luci'] = ['black cat']
graph['echo'] = ['pitbull']
graph['dante'] = ['pitbull']
graph['ginger'] = ['orange cat']
graph['simon'] = ['black lab']

print search(graph, 'mariela', 'walter')
```

Here is a demo https://repl.it/IkRA/0

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: I've run your code with --- print search(graph, 'walter', 'german shepherd') -- it did not return the right output. I received an error instead.

Comment: the reason being that there is no node called 'pitbull' Even if though you have child nodes called `pitbull`, you don't have a node in your graph called 'pitbull' Either A) `graph['pitbull'] = [ ]` or B) change this line `queue.extend(graph[node])` to `queue.extend(graph.get(node, [ ]))`